# Jquery drag and drop the button onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I am trying to move the button to the next div by clicking the button not by drag and drop.This code is taken from w3schools website.My question is that is it possible to move the button to the next div by clicking the button instead by drag and drop

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      #div1, #div2 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      </style>
      <script>
      function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
      }

      function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>

      <h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
      <p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

      <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
      </div>

      <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: If you want to do something like show and hide of button, then use jquery show and hide instead of this. & create separate buttons in both div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #div1,
        #div2 {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 35px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
        function move(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var target = (ev.target.parentNode.id == 'div1') ? 'div2' : 'div1';
            document.getElementById(target).appendChild(ev.target);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
    <p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onClick="move(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
    </div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You can check this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      #div1, #div2 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      #button2 {
        display: none;
      }
      </style>
      <script>
      function moveButton(e) {
        let btn1 = document.getElementById('button1');
        let btn2 = document.getElementById('button2');
        let btn_id = e.target.id;
        if(btn_id == "button1"){
            e.target.style.display = 'none';
            btn2.style.display= 'block';
        } else {
            e.target.style.display = 'none';
            btn1.style.display= 'block';
        }
      }

      </script>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div id="div1">
        <button id="button1" onClick="moveButton(event)">Click Me</button>
      </div>

      <div id="div2"><button id="button2" onClick="moveButton(event)">Click Me</button></div>


      </body>
      </html>
```